# Журналы транзакций

Tags: sql, sql-server

Как найти на сервере базу данных с самым большим журналом транзакций?

Comment: `select NAME, size from sys.database_files  where type_desc = 'log'`  Не понятно как обратиться ко всему серверу сразу и как выделить только максимальные значения размера логов...

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так, чуть поправил

```sql
DECLARE @size TABLE
(
    DBName sysname,
      Name NVARCHAR(200),
      Size INT
)
INSERT INTO @size( DBName, Name, Size)
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 'use [?]
SELECT TOP 1 DB_NAME(), name, size from sys.database_files WHERE type_desc = ''LOG'' ORDER BY size DESC'
SELECT * FROM @size
-- 
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM @size ORDER BY Size DESC -- Максимальный
```

Comment: Немного мудрено для моего уровня, но все работает спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Зайдите в папку с базами проводником, упорядочите файлы по размеру - и найдите самый большой файл с расширением .ldf

Comment: Спасибо, но файлы лежат на большом количестве разных дисков, нужно найти путем запроса в базу.